# How to resize inflated layout with attribute set in Android custom view?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view

I am creating a custom view by inflating from a layout as following:

CustomView.java

```
public class CustomView extends FrameLayout {
    public CustomView(@NonNull Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public CustomView(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public CustomView(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);

        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.custom_view, this, true);
    }
}
```

custom_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    ...

</FrameLayout>
```

My problem is that when I use this custom view in the layout with some layout_width and layout_height values, the content inside does not resize with the new value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your `CustomView` extends `FrameLayout` and the root of `custom_view.xml` is also `FrameLayout`, you can use [merge](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html#Merge).

Just change the root of `custom_view.xml` to `<merge></merge>`.